# Problems using Maven to initialize a local thoughtsite (App Engine sample) project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven-2

This sample app ("thoughtsite") for App Engine contains a pom.xml in its trunk:

http://code.google.com/p/thoughtsite/source/browse/#svn/trunk

I ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and also tried using m2eclipse to import this source code into an Eclipse project.

But I end up with this error despite the fact that I have the Google App Engine plugin and the Google App Engine SDK installed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkImplInfo.<clinit>(SdkImplInfo.java:19)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Logging.initializeLogging(Logging.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to discover the Google App Engine SDK root. This code should be loaded from the SDK directory, but was instead loaded from file:~/.m2/repository/com/google/appengine/appengine-tools-sdk/1.3.0/appengine-tools-sdk-1.3.0.jar.  Specify -Dappengine.sdk.root to override the SDK location.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo.findSdkRoot(SdkInfo.java:106)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.info.SdkInfo.<clinit>(SdkInfo.java:24)
    ... 3 more
```

When I go into the project settings under "Google" and try to set it to use the default App Engine SDK it always reverts to trying to use Maven's App Engine SDK instead. No idea how to get this project working.

Comment: Have you tried running mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dappengine.sdk.root=/path/to/sdk/root ?

Comment: Yes. After doing that, when I go into the project settings under "Google" and try to set it to use the default App Engine SDK it still reverts to trying to use Maven's App Engine SDK instead.

Comment: I use the maven-gae-plugin without the Eclipse Google App Engine plugin because the maven-gae-plugin does everything I need. You may want to look into using it as well. If you did then compiling your app would be as simple as running gae:unpack to get the latest SDK into your local .m2 respository and then clean compile.

Comment: @Taylor Leese: Thanks. That looks good. Now, stupid question: How do you install it? I tried just dropping the JAR file from http://code.google.com/p/maven-gae-plugin/downloads/detail?name=maven-gae-plugin-0.5.9.jar into my Eclipse plugins directory but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I have gone through the integration with Eclipse, Maven and GAE and wrote a [blog post](http://hamandeggs.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/how-to-gae-eclipse-maven/) about it. Briefly, to get a working example just run: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0-alpha-4:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.beardedgeeks -DarchetypeArtifactId=gae-eclipse-maven-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.1.2 -DarchetypeRepository=http://beardedgeeks.googlecode.com/svn/repository/releases` It may use an outdated version of the SDK, but updating it shouldn't be an issue.